# Cannot upload chunked video to twitter

Tags: twitter

I have been trying to upload video chunks to twitter using twurl as in the example on the page: https://blog.twitter.com/2015/rest-api-now-supports-native-video-upload

However, I get the "unsupported video" error. I am able to upload smaller sized videos without breaking them into chunks.

I am running twurl on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly "unsupported video".
Twitter has a strict video format requirement: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media#videorecs.

Example: sample mp4 files containing 6-channel audio won't be supported.

Check out my project: https://github.com/mtrung/TwitterVideoUpload.